# Javascript script for form submit doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried to intercept a submit form by javascript script but it doesn't work .

this is my html code :

```
<form id="myForm" action="home1" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="user_email" name="email" /> 
    <input type="password" id="user_password" name="password" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn bg-olive btn-block">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Script:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) 
{
    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('success');
});
});
```

Comment: Check the developer console. Your code looks like it has syntax errors.

Comment: Once you use proper formatting it's obvious what the issue is...

Comment: Sorry, I'm a new member.

Comment: No, once you use correct formatting in *your code*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a superfluous `});`in line 23.

Comment: thanks, you are right. But what makes me post this idiot code is that I don't understand why the script must be declared in the body(exactly after the form).
l mean why it doesn't work when I declare it in the head!?

Comment: Because the elements don't exist at that point. You should use jQuery's ready handler.

Comment: Now i understand .Thank you Lee .